# Consequences of Article VI, Clause 1 of the U.S. Constitution and the 11th Article of Confederation

Tags: canada, us-constitution

Article VI, Clause 1 of the Constitution of the United States, known as the Engagements Clause, says:

> All Debts contracted and Engagements entered into, before the Adoption of this Constitution, shall be as valid against the United States under this Constitution, as under the Confederation.

The eleventh Article of Confederation says Canada will be admitted into the United States as a new state whenever it so chooses, without any need for an act of Congress to admit them.

Would this mean that if Canada were to decide tomorrow to become a new state in the U.S., it would be immediately admitted without an act of Congress?

Comment: Through the radification of the **Treaty of Ghent**, that Article probably became moot.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Why the Treaty of Ghent and not the Treaty of Paris?

Comment: @Justaguy The main US goal of the war of 1812 was the occupation of  (Upper) Canada. By that time most of it had been settled by former Loyalists but also US Citizens. The US expected a 'warm' welcome as liberators, but the opposite was true. The Treaty of Ghent established the status quo ante bellum; accepting the previous borders (1795 Jay Treaty). The British also addressed the impressment of sailors from American ships, which was a second major cause. The final result was the transition from a reluctant to a normalization of the relations between the two countries.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That makes sense. If I understand you correctly, *I* would rewrite your first comment, to say *the latest* this article could have been rendered moot was with the signing of the Treaty of Ghent. I'd say it that way because I think there's a good chance it was actually rendered moot much earlier, with the adoption of the Constitution. Even if I'm wrong, I agree with you that it couldn't have remained in effect after the Treaty of Ghent.

Comment: @Justaguy Well comments can't be edited. Since in 1812 it is clear that the US hoped that Canada would become a part of the US and that after 1814 a (more or less) pratical relationship existed, the **Treaty of Ghent** seems to me the point where those hopes were abandoned.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Sorry, I was afraid that would be confusing. I didn't mean that you should change your answer, only that I would say it differently, because I think this clause was rendered moot earlier. I may be wrong on the details, and in some broader sense of mootness, you are surely right: After Ghent, the whole project, of which this clause was one little part, was abandoned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102453/discussion-between-mark-johnson-and-just-a-guy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for two reasons:

1) The engagements referred to include all *non-debt* financial or economic obligations, such as contracts. This usage was common at the time. For example, Art. II of the *[Northwest Ordinance](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/18th_century/nworder.asp)* says,

> no law ought ever...interfere with or affect private contracts or *engagements*, bona fide, and without fraud, previously formed.

2) Even if they cover more than financial obligations, engagements imply mutuality, which was lacking in the offer to Canada. (That offer was made in desperation at the beginning of the Revolutionary War, when the US was desperate for allies. The US was so enamored of Canada that they tried to get it in the Treaty of Paris which ended the War.)